# How can I undo a revert that I made on github without losing all my commits on a protected branch?

Tags: git, github, git-revert

I have a protected develop branch that will not let you push directly to it from your terminal.  We did a revert to a previous commit, directly from github.  After doing the revert, when making a pull request, some of the changes that should be included in the pull request are not showing.  How can I undo the revert without doing a force push and losing all of our current commits?

I have tried making a pull request, pushing directly to the branch (it is protected and will not let me).

When trying to push directly from my local branch to the remote branch I get this error:

! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)

If possible, I want to just go back to the state it was at before the revert, so that all files in our pull requests will be recognized.

Comment: A "revert' is just a commit. It is created automatically to under some *other* commit, but it's still just a normal commit. You can revert the revert commit, exactly as you reverted  the *first* commit, using whatever tool you used to create the first revert.